# Grid based Collision Detection between circles

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection, collision-resolution, grid

I am working on a 2d arcade game where I have 5 types of circles with different sizes: The ship, the missiles, and 3 types of monsters.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Currently I'm using brute force collision detection where I check every missile vs. every monster without taking probability of collision into account. Sadly, this makes the process REALLY slow.

This here is my Grid class, but it's incomplete. I'd greatly appreciate your help.

```
    public class Grid {

    int rows;
    int cols;
    double squareSize;
    private ArrayList<Circle>[][] grid;

    public Grid(int sceneWidth, int sceneHeight, int squareSize) {
        this.squareSize = squareSize;
// Calculate how many rows and cols for the grid.
        rows = (sceneHeight + squareSize) / squareSize;
        cols = (sceneWidth + squareSize) / squareSize;
// Create grid
        this.grid = (ArrayList[][]) new ArrayList[cols][rows]; //Generic array creation error workaround
    }

The addObject method inside the Grid class.
    public void addObject(Circle entity) {
// Adds entity to every cell that it's overlapping with.
        double topLeftX = Math.max(0, entity.getLayoutX() / squareSize);
        double topLeftY = Math.max(0, entity.getLayoutY() / squareSize);
        double bottomRightX = Math.min(cols - 1, entity.getLayoutX() + entity.getRadius() - 1) / squareSize;
        double bottomRightY = Math.min(rows - 1, entity.getLayoutY() + entity.getRadius() - 1) / squareSize;

        for (double x = topLeftX; x < bottomRightX; x++) {
            for (double y = topLeftY; y < bottomRightY; y++) {
                grid[(int) x][(int) y].add(entity); //Cast types to int to prevent loosy conversion type error.
            }
        }
    }
```

But that's where I am at a complete loss. I'm not even sure the source code I provided is correct. Please let me know how to make the grid based collision work. I've read basically every tutorial I could get my hands on but without much effect. 
Thanks.

Comment: You didn't mention your problem ? What is the wrong behaviour you're  getting ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is how I implement a grid-based collision. Also, I'm quite certain my Grid class is incomplete. I do not know how to write the code to make uniform grid collision happen in my 2d game.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite I am struggling with writing the source code. I understand the concept, but I do not know how to put it in action.

Comment: @user2915567 See this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/39931/fast-accurate-2d-collision/39932#39932
It has been duplicated several times. :) You have to ask a specific question about a specific step you are stuck with. Otherwise use an engine that already does collisions (there are many).

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite I would like to write the code all by myself in order to learn more. Can you please refer me to a similar program that uses a grid for its collision and has all the necessary source code?

Comment: If you want to learn it, you are probably not ready to read source. There are N questions about it. What part of the implementation process don't you understand? If you can't answer that, you don't know what you don't know, how can we know? BTW, you"ll learn a lot more by using an engine correctly than by implementing things yourself often times because it is far more practical.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite What engine do you recommend that I use in that case?

Comment: It entirely depends on your goals which I don't know.:) There is a list of engines here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines ... If you manage to make a decent game wouldn't you be happy you didn't waste time recreating an existing mechanic? Use what already exists if it suits your purpose. Otherwise you might as well re-write the whole OS from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Given the image depicting a very manageable number of spheres you shouldn't have any problem checking every missile against every enemy.

You haven't shown us the relevant code, but my best guess it that you are not using basic sphere-to-sphere collision detection like you should.

Basically every sphere has a centre position and a radius. For every pair of spheres, if the distance between the centres is less than the sum of their radii the spheres intersect, otherwise they don't. If you implement this method right there should be no need to worry about performance unless you need to do a million or more checks per frame.